# Opening an url dataset with xarray.open_dataset through a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-xarray

Hello I am trying to make a tutorial (https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/Satellite_Data/goes-interactive-plot) that uses the function xarray.open_dataset to retrive an url dataset but I am failing to open the dataset very likely because of my institution proxy.

Do somebody know how the xarray.open_dataset function can be configured to work in a network that uses a proxy?

Comment: Why do you think the proxy is the problem? What error are you getting during which line, exactly?